# Compare the two lists and change the value of the properties of the objects in one of the lists

Tags: ios, swift

I have the two lists of AddItem objects. AddItem is a custom object made of data downloaded from the web. The second one list is also AddItem, but this one is saved in the database. I use it to create another list, but in this case user of the app decides which object are important for him.
This want I want to achieve is to mark every single object of the first AddItem list (not saved in the database, create during the start of the view), to show in the TableView which one is saved in the database, so I already use him in another view. You know what I mean. There is a TableView list and if I am interested in a cell I select it and add it to the database.
I hope I have described it clearly. If not, ask for questions.

The first AddItem list (not saved in the database):

```
func setAddItemList(stations: [Station], sensors: [Sensor]) {
    var addItems = [AddItem]()
    var sensorItems = [SensorItem]()
    let falseValue = RealmOptional<Bool>(false)
    addList = try persistenceService.fetchAddItems().toArray(ofType: AddItem.self) //The second list with saved data in the database
    
    let addItem = stations.map { station in
        AddItem(
            id: station.id,
            stationId: station.id,
            cityName: station.city?.name ?? "",
            addressStreet: station.addressStreet!,
            added: falseValue,
            sensor: [])
    }
    addItems.append(contentsOf: addItem)
```

As you can see, it's create by already downloaded data. I decided to add the property - added, which is the bool property and mark it as true if selected the right cell. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this when creating a list of AddItem objects. The saved array is almost the same. There is only more data, but ids, names, addresses and so on are same, so there are loads of the same data for comparison

Answer (score 0):

I made the solution myself:

```
addItem.forEach { item in
        guard let index = addList2.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id})
            else {
                print("Failed to find the SavedAddItem for the AddItem \(item.id)")
                return
        }
        addItems[index + 1].added = trueValue
    }
```